# How can I add more sources files to a target after the target has been created in cmake

Tags: cmake

I use the following example to show my question： suppose now I have created a target using the following commands in CMake:

```
add_custom_target(MyProject  SOURCES a.txt b.txt)
```

After this target is created, more files are put to the target, and in order to do that I use the following command:

```
   set(moreFiles c.txt d.txt e.txt)
   set_target_properties(MyProject PROPERTIES SOURCES  ${moreFiles})
```

However, in VC the added files to the target is only c.txt, other files such as a.txt,b.txt,d.txt and e.txt are not available in the target. Anything I can do for improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-trivial manipulations with properties, it's best to forego the shorthand functions like `set_target_properties` and use the full power of `set_property`:

```
set_property(TARGET MyProject APPEND PROPERTY SOURCES ${moreFiles})
```

If, for some reason, you'd want to keep using `set_target_properties` for that, you'd have to query the current value first, and quote the entire result:

```
get_property(currentFiles TARGET MyProject PROPERTY SOURCES)
set_target_properties(MyProject PROPERTIES SOURCES "${currentFiles};${moreFiles}")
```

The quoting is important, because the shorthand `set_*_properties` commands expect their arguments to be `... PROPERTIES prop1 value1 prop2 value2`, that is, an alternating list of property names and values. Your original command set the property `SOURCES` to `c.txt`, and then the property `d.txt` to the value `e.txt`.