# how could I link source_group() with a specific target in cmake

Tags: cmake

In cmake `source_group` can be used to put a certain number of files within a folder under a target. Normally the created folder will belongs to the target that are created by the files within the folder. However, in some situations, the created target may be not so directly linked to the files as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180851/how-can-i-add-more-sources-files-to-a-target-after-the-target-has-been-created-i) shows. In this case, how can we link the `source_group` with the target?

Comment: What's `add_group`? Is that from a module? The native CMake mechanism for grouping files into project folders is [`source_group`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/source_group.html), which does not care about targets.

Comment: @Angew Thanks, and I made a mistake.

Comment: My other question still stands, though. What do you mean with "link `source_group` with the target?" `source_group` operates on files only, not on targets. Can you shed some more light on what problem(s) you have?

Comment: @Angew source_group is used to define a group into which sources will be placed in project files. The project files are targets in CMake. Usually, we will use add_library, add_executable to generate a target, which is a project file.  It is true that the added files will be put in a directory when using source_group, but the directory is always within a certain a project file.

Comment: Yes. But `source_group` simply says "file A goes into folder B/C." It will go to that folder in *all* targets in which it's included.

Comment: @Angew No, it is not always the case. The linked post I mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180851/how-can-i-add-more-sources-files-to-a-target-after-the-target-has-been-created-i, for example, does not work. In that post, the files will be put in a target as expected. However, using source_group will not put them in a folder.

Comment: Then that's most likely a bug in CMake. You might want to clarify this on the CMake mailing list (cmake@cmake.org) and potentially file a CMake bug report. Still, it has nothing to do with targets. `source_group` works on files alone, it does not interact with targets at all. It's probably just that when making the property `SOURCES` modifiable (which is a fairly recent addition to CMake), nobody thought to cross-check it with `source_group`.

Comment: I'm too interested in this question. Since each target is a separate project in VS, it makes perfect sense to allow grouping sources differently for different targets.